# Shiny server.ui not reacting to a conditional argument inputfile

Tags: r, file-io, conditional-statements, shiny

I've written a shiny apps to do some calculations on a RMarkdown document. In the ui.R there is a condition for how many single fileinput to insert, as the input files. However for some reason, the Rmarkdown only reads the last file. I know I could use multiple files but I'd like to avoid cases where the files are not in the right order. Also, I think I am calling the right datapath row. When I remove the conditions and literally have 4 input files, then it works fine.

```
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Drift Report"),
        selectInput("n",
                "Number of files:",
                choices = c(1,2,3,4)),
    checkboxInput("d", label = "Data Summary", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("k", label = "Drift Plots", value = FALSE),    
    radioButtons("p", label = "Plot Type", 
                       choices = list("Point Plot" = 1, "Cumm Plot"=2, "Both - Side by Side"=3, "Both - One underneath the Other"=4),selected = NULL,inline=TRUE),
    sliderInput("s","No of Plots", min = 1, max = 50, value = 10, width = "40%"),
    submitButton("Apply Changes"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.n == 1",
      fileInput("dat","File Upload for Analysis", accept = ".eff")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.n == 2",
      fileInput("dat","1st File Upload for Analysis"),
      fileInput("dat3","2nd File Upload for Analysis")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.n == 3",
      fileInput("dat","1st File Upload for Analysis"),
      fileInput("dat3","2nd File Upload for Analysis"),
      fileInput("dat4","3rd File Upload for Analysis")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.n == 4",
      fileInput("dat","1st File Upload for Analysis"),
      fileInput("dat3","2nd File Upload for Analysis"),
      fileInput("dat4","3rd File Upload for Analysis"),
      fileInput("dat5","4th File Upload for Analysis")
    ),
    uiOutput('markdown')
  )
)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  library(shiny)
  library(markdown)
  library(knitr)
  output$markdown <- renderUI({
    HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('RMarkdown_pdf3.Rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
  })
})
```

When I do the ugly way, one by one, it works fine

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Drift Report"),
    selectInput("n",
                "Number of files:",
                choices = c(1,2,3,4)),
    checkboxInput("d", label = "Data Summary", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("k", label = "Drift Plots", value = FALSE),    
    radioButtons("p", label = "Plot Type", 
                       choices = list("Point Plot" = 1, "Cumm Plot"=2, "Both - Side by Side"=3, "Both - One underneath the Other"=4),selected = NULL,inline=TRUE),
    sliderInput("s","No of Plots", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10, width = "40%"),
    submitButton("Apply Changes"),
    HTML('<br>'),
    helpText(h4("Upload only the necessary files")),
    fileInput("dat","1st File Upload", accept = ".eff"),
    fileInput("dat3","2nd File upload",accept = ".eff"),
    fileInput("dat4","3rd File upload",accept = ".eff"),
    fileInput("dat5","4th File upload",accept = ".eff"),
    HTML('<hr>'),
    uiOutput('markdown')
  )
)
```

This is how I am calling for the uploaded files:

```
dat <- data.f(input$dat[[1, 'datapath']])
```

Any idea where this could be broken under the condition settings?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I have not dealt with this before, but looks like `fileInput` takes a `multiple` argument that is FALSE by default. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Gopala, indeed this is the default "FALSE", however I'd like to work with single file inputs anyways.